# In Python, how to perform logistic regression for data set containing very large values of x and very small values of y?

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am trying to fit logistic function to a data set containing very large x values (1000's) and very small y values (1e-4). As shown in the code below, if I execute the code the interpreter returns

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.
```

If I multiply the ydata by 1000, then the curve_fit function successfully fits it. But then I would have to divide some of the fitted values by 1000. Is there a way to curve fit these extreme values without changing the original values?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq, curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def logistic(x, N, A, b, y0):
    return N / (1 + A*b**-x) + y0

xdata = np.array([100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500])
ydata = np.array([0, 1e-6, 6.5e-5, 1.5e-4, 4.2e-4, 5.5e-4, 5.8e-4])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(logistic, xdata, ydata)

x = np.linspace(0, 2500, 50)
y = logistic(x, *popt)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x,y, label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Also, would it be possible to fit the curve in the forms of exponential for the logistic function, such as (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)?

```
def logistic_e(x, N, b, y0, x0):
    return N / (1 + np.exp(-b*(x-x0))) + y0
```

If I use logistic_e, then no matter how I modify the dataset, I always receive

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:779: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated  category=OptimizeWarning)
```

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try transforming the scales like [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform) or [`Normalizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer) for X and [`MinMaxScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform) for y. After predicting y, you could use [`inverse_transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform) on `MinMaxScaler` to rescale it in to your range of interest.

Comment: I have scaled the data and was able to fit the graphs. I can also inverse_transform and plot the values corresponding to the original data set. Would you know a way to correlate the scaling to the curve_fit coefficients for the logistic function?

Comment: Interesting question. Try applying inverse transform on the coefficients too. Logically it should make sense

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep adjusting your maxfev value,this is extremely high number so adjust as fits

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(logistic, xdata, ydata, maxfev=1005000)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Using the maximum maxfev still results in the same error in this case. I had to insert guessed p0 for it to successfully compute. I am unsure if there is a more automated way to estimate p0.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale your data, for example, you can use Sklearn preprocessing:

[enter link description here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)